# How to draw overlays with outer border in MapKit?

Tags: ios, swift, mapkit

Is it possible to draw overlay like this with using `MapKit` in `Swift`?

[image]

I searched online and haven't found any useful advice.

Comment: Overlay like what? Are you taking about the blue line? The gray/black line? There's certainly documentation about [how to add overlays](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/LocationAwarenessPG/AnnotatingMaps/AnnotatingMaps.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009497-CH6-SW16) to a map. Although the example code might be Objective-C, converting to Swift syntax is straightforward.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way I've found is to draw a fatter line underneath your main polyline, thereby adding a stroke to both sides of your main polyline.

When you define your main polyline(s), add a zIndex:

```
mainPolyline.strokeColor = UIColor.white
mainPolyline.strokeWidth = 2
mainPolyline.zIndex = 10
mainPolyline.map = mapView
```

Then add another polyline with the same path, modifying your original's strokeWidth and zIndex:

```
let lowerPolyLine = GMSPolyline(path: samePathAsYourMainPolyline)
lowerPolyLine.strokeWidth = mainPolyline.strokeWidth + 1
lowerPolyLine.strokeColor = UIColor.black
lowerPolyLine.zIndex = mainPolyline.zIndex - 1
lowerPolyLine.map = mapView;
```

If you are using map kit then [here](https://github.com/nighthawk/ASPolylineView) is a fully customisable library you can use.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks, but the thing is I need this done in MapKit.

Comment: Ok. Updated the answer for MapKit.